# How can I replace "cat" and "echo" read/write command with python/c program?

Tags: command-line, python, echo

I have trouble replacing device in/output commands like:

```
echo 100 > /dev/rtmotor_raw_l0   # output 100hz frequency
```

```
cat /dev/rtswitch0 # read switch state
```

### output problem(python)

I tried replacing that command with python.

```
file = open('/dev/rtmotor_raw_l0','w')
file.write('100\n')            # I want output in this timing
file.close()                   # output reflected after closing file
```

The problem is that the output appears after closing the file.
Does this mean I have to open and close this device each time I want to change its value? Also, changing `'w'` to `'a'` did not work.

### input problem(python)

Almost the same problem happens in input observation.

```
file = open('/dev/rtswitch','r')
file.read()  # works
file.read()  # after first read it does't work anymore
file.close() # need to reopen the file to get newer value
```

I could only read 1 input in each opening files.

So, currently **I have to reopen the devices each time I want to write/read new values**.
Are there any way to avoid this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: After the first read, the file pointer is at the end of the file; assuming `'/dev/rtswitch` is seekable, you need to rewind the file pointer to the beginning of the file before you can read the contents again: put `file.seek(0)` between the two reads.

Answer (score 1):

Try call `file.flush()` after `write()` call. It will flush buffer to file and you can read data.